# Authenticate the KEY File in Certificate using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

As in Postman we have certificate and key file, how do I validate the KEY file using c# or MVC. I have tried adding the below code but seems like for the KEY file we've some other code to write. Please suggest some help.

```
string base64cert = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(pemFilePath));
var cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(base64cert), certAuthCode);
cert.PrivateKey = null;
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(crtFilePath));
//For Key File Path
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(crtKeyPath));
```